# how to open a file in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
path1="c:/amit_150000.txt"
v=1
fs=File.open("$path"+"#{v}",'w')
```

Now I have to open that file but I am not able to. Please tell me the problem.

Comment: What happens when you do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
fs = File.open("#{path1}#{v}",'w')
```

Comment: sir cud u plzz explin how it will work

Comment: path1="c:/kabab.txt"
 path2="c:/kabab2.txt"
 for v in 1..2
 puts "#{path}"#{v}" 
end 
now tell me how it will create two file

Comment: I have posted an answer to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194447/how-to-solve-this-equation-in-ruby).

Answer (score 1):

You can open a `.rb` file in **command prompt**.

Here are the steps:

1. Open the command prompt *(search for 'command prompt' or 'cmd.exe.')*
   you should see this:

   ```
   C:\Users\username>
   ```
2. For example I am keeping this file in Desktop and in a folder named Ruby,
   type in the path to the folder like this:

   ```
   cd Desktop\Ruby
   ```

   You should see this:

   ```
   C:\Users\username\Desktop\Ruby>
   ```
3. Enter the name of the folder, then the file name:

   ```
   Ruby *example.rb*
   ```
4. If else fails, check your code for errors. The command prompt will give you 
   a hint for example:

   ```
   example.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
   ```

   This means that your error has something to do with the code, *end*, and is on line 5.

Good luck opening a *.rb* file!