# how to solve this equation in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
path1="c:/kabab.txt"
path2="c:/kabab2.txt"
for v in 1..2
puts "#{path}"#{v}"
end
```

I would like to create a file, but I'm not able to do that.

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby you can't retrieve the *value* of a local variable from its *name* using the approach you've tried. There is `instance_variable_get` for instance variables but there isn't an equivalent for local variables as far as I know.

`"path#{v}"` is a string containing the name of your variable so if you evaluate that using `eval` the result from the eval will be the value of the variable. Therefore you could do something like:

```
filename = eval("path#{v}")
open(filename, 'w')
```

but you always need to be careful when using `eval` because of potential security issues.

Instead, I would put the list of files in an array

```
paths = ["c:/kabab.txt", "c:/kabab2.txt"]
```

and do:

```
paths.each do |path|
  f = open(path, 'w')
  # use file here
end
```

or if all the files share a common prefix and extension then something like:

```
prefix = "c:/kabab"
extension = ".txt"
for v in 1..2
  filename = "#{prefix}#{v}#{extension}"
  # use filename here
end
```

Comment: oh thanks mikej u really know ruby very well i also asked about platinfo["telnet_id"] i hope u remember me

Comment: mikej the last u told will create different file name like
kabab1.txt and kabab2.txt i want to create different filename using loop??

Comment: @amit Yes, I remember you from your other question. The examples I gave use a loop to create the different filenames. Please can you explain a bit more if these suggestions still don't do what you want.

Comment: but mikej one thing u told i m not able to get you said like we can't access local variable by their name but i do like that
a=10
puts a
i m able to get the value of a by just puuting its name
sorry if i m wrong

Comment: If I have `a=10` and I have `b="a"` i.e. `b` is a String containing the **name** of another variable then I can't get 10, the **value** of the variable named in `b` without using `eval`. In other languages this is possible e.g in PHP where `$$` can be used to *dereference* a variable. e.g. if I had `$a=10` and `$b="a"` in PHP then `print $$b` would print 10. This is close to what you were trying to do in the original code in your question.